# Azure B2C: email field is blank in MFA method EMAIL

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using B2C custom policies which allows users to sign-in with the username instead of the email. and select default MFA method.

When signing in and selecting Email MFA, I don't see the email populated.

I have implemented this policy: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="EmailVerifyOnSignIn">
      <DisplayName>EmailVerifyOnSignIn</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <!-- Required claims -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isActiveMFASession" DefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteMFAMethod"></ValidationTechnicalProfile>
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-MFA" />
    </TechnicalProfile>


    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonName">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" Required="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <PersistedClaims>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="SomeDefaultDisplayNameValue" />
        <!-- Optional claims. -->
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
      </PersistedClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" PartnerClaimType="newClaimsPrincipalCreated" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonName">
      <DisplayName>User ID signup</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
        <Item Key="LocalAccountType">Username</Item>
        <Item Key="LocalAccountProfile">true</Item>
        <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" Required="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonName" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingUsername-NoError">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">An account could not be found for the provided user ID.</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" Required="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <!-- Required claims -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
        <!--
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="secondaryStrongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationAlternativePhoneNumber" />
          -->
        <!-- Optional claims -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" PartnerClaimType="upn" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username">
      <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonUsernameExchange</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Username</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.showSignupLink">false</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.enableRememberMe">True</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkOverride">ForgotPasswordExchange</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkLocation">AfterButtons</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" DefaultValue="{OIDC:Username}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingUserNameAndValidateStrongAuthenticationEmailAddress">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" Required="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountEnabled" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <!--displayName added to Claims-->
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertEmailAndstrongAuthenticationEmailAddressAreEqual" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertAccountEnabledIsTrue" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromObjectID" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-ReadCommon" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-ReadCommon">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateOtherMailsFromEmail" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CopyEmailToReadOnly" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

•   It is because when you are **`using the ‘B2C_EmailOrPhoneMFA policy’ you are using the extension attributes for storing the extension properties and adding the application ObjectID due to which it is being considered as untrusted domain application since the session is interrupted by closing and reopening the same due to which the session token might be considered expired/invalid immediately. As a result of which, the ‘email’ claim is not getting populated`**.

•   Also, since **you are using the user flow through the custom policy, the cache regarding the user’s email ID entered in the first step is not stored in the browser cache according to the ‘UserJourney’ path defined in the custom policy**. Thus, would suggest you to **please ensure that the below ‘ClaimsProvider’ section is included in your custom policy for the email ID to be remembered through the ‘LocalAccountSignIn’ technical profile Id**: -

```
<ClaimsProvider>
<DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
<TechnicalProfiles>
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="setting.enableRememberMe">True</Item>
  </Metadata>
</TechnicalProfile>
</TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Please find the below link for more details regarding the above: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#add-the-metadata-to-the-self-asserted-technical-profile***

Thus, by following the above, you should be able to populate the email ID automatically in the user flow of the custom policy.

Comment: Do you mean to say KMSI option with remember the user email even though user dont select KMSI checkbox? by the way KMSI option in already active in my policy and its not helping with the  issue.

Comment: Ok...Kindly please try using the given technical profile in your custom policy, may be it will be of help to you since it is about remembering the local account signin email.

Comment: In my policy users are signing in with username not email, already tried the provided TP,no joy